# HTML Document formatting, removing <br> based on a pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML document that follows this pattern:

```
text1
text2
number
<br>
```

So basically:

```
<div id = "stuff">
Jacksonville Que
<br>
Jack Johnson Qc
<br>
160,786,000
<br>
Janesonville pour l'elaboration de
<br>
Janesonville for policy of
<br>
150,585,685
<br>
......
</div>
```

I essentially want to convern this information into a table so it looks like:

```
-----------------------------------------
|Text1 Text2 Text3 | Number             |
-----------------------------------------
```

I know I can do something like:

```
$("#stuff").map(function(){ return $(this).text() }).get().join(', ')
```

But this removes all `<br>s` - I'm having trouble coming up with the code that will take the pattern into account. This becomes more problematic because There can be 1 line of text before the number or 3 - thats not set, the only REAL definate pattern is that when a number is presented then the row ends, and a new row starts.

Comment: Select all the child nodes of the stuff div with native js, filter out all nodes that aren't text nodes or break tags, then iterate over them and place them the way you want. jQuery doesn't really help a whole lot in dealing with text manipulation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some iteration with a few checks along the way should solve that :

```
var table = $('<table />');
var tr    = $('<tr />');

$("#stuff").contents().each(function(i, node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3 && 'nodeValue' in node && node.nodeValue.trim().length) {
        node = node.nodeValue.trim();
        var isNumb = !isNaN(parseInt(node.replace(/\,/g,'').trim()));

        $('<td />', {text: node}).appendTo(tr);
        tr = isNumb ? $('<tr />') : tr; // if number, create new row
        table.append(tr);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wukQf/)

Answer (score 1):

throw my 2 cents in:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LY3pZ/)

```
<div id = "stuff">
    Jacksonville Que
    <br/>
    Jack Johnson Qc
    <br/>
    160,786,000
    <br/>
    Janesonville pour l'elaboration de
    <br/>
    Janesonville for policy of
    <br/>
    Janesonville for zczdzc policy offff
    <br/>
    150,585,685
    <br/>
</div>
```

js:

```
var str = jQuery('#stuff').text();
var tokens = str.split(/\n/);
var val = '';
var j = 0;
var out = [];
out[j] = [];
for(var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
    val = tokens[i].trim();
    if(val !== ''){
        out[j].push(val);
        if(val.match(/(\d+,?)/)){
            j++;
            out[j] = [];
        }
    }

}
out.pop();
console.log(out);
```

outputs array, then do as you please with it

```
[
Array[3]
0: "Jacksonville Que"
1: "Jack Johnson Qc"
2: "160,786,000"
, 
Array[4]
0: "Janesonville pour l'elaboration de"
1: "Janesonville for policy of"
2: "Janesonville for zczdzc policy offff"
3: "150,585,685"
]
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this one more since I actually used this one - even though the above answer gave me the table I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

may be because you are using `.text()`
try to use it with `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = $.grep($("#stuff").text().split("\n"), function(n, i) {
    if (n != "") return n;
});
var result = new Array();
$.each(arr, function(i, n) {
    result.push(n);
    if (((i + 1)%3) == 0) {
        console.debug(result.join(" "));
        result = new Array();
    }
});
```

result :

```
Jacksonville Que Jack Johnson Qc 160,786,000 
Janesonville pour l'elaboration de Janesonville for policy of 150,585,685
```